# yii2 css is not working with pdf creation?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, yii2

I am using yii2 and want to convert my html view to pdf format, for that I have use 
[mPDF yii2 install](https://github.com/robregonm/yii2-pdf) .

In my controller action , I am doing this:

```
public function actionPdf(){
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';
     $this->layout = '//print';
    return $this->render('myview', []);
}
```

When I remove `Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';` this line from action. I always get my correct view with css. [image: view without pdf]

But when I use `Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';` this for pdf generation , I get only pdf view without css.

I have included my CSS file in layout. What should I have to do for getting my correct pdf view?

Comment: I have same problem My css is not working ata time of pdf converter.I am using plugin of pdf

Comment: I will add my code..Please help me a i am new in yii2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832306/how-to-set-css-at-time-of-pdf-creation-in-yii2....I have post my question on this link...Please help me I am new in yii2

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you included the CSS inline?
2. [Is the CSS you expect allowed by mPDF?](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34)

Basically, `yii2-pdf` is a thin wrapper around the `mPDF` library. It will not include your styles if they are required through a `<link`, only if they are included as a `<style` tag.