# How to set css at time of PDF creation in yii2?

Tags: php, pdf, yii2

**Pdf fuction***
 This function is call from ajax after getting data from this function it's call anothe file here I am display data which is coming from data base.That file all css part in style tag using then as it is style tag prind in pdf as a text and if this all css file include in css folder then pdf is not create in proper format

```
public function actionInvoicespacking(){ 
    $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
    $modelShipment = Shipment::find()->orderBy('ship_id DESC')->one();
    if(count($modelShipment) == 0) {

      $shipid= 1;
    } else 
    {
     $shipid= $modelShipment->ship_id;

   }
   $htmlContent = file_get_contents('http://localhost/shepherdlogistics_v1.0/backend/views/shipment/invoicespackingdata.php');
   $pdf->content = $htmlContent;
   return $pdf->render();

 }
```

**invoicespackingdata.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.fontawesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylepdf.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: cambria;
    }

    .nopadd {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-lg-2 nopadd">
                <img src="logopdf.png" alt="logo" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h1 style="font-size: 55px;font-weight: bold; padding: 23px 0px;">
                SHEPHERD LOGISTICS CO. W.L.L.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which PDF library used?

Comment: in yii2 add use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

Answer (score 0):

As the [demo](http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf) states:

> Any `<style>` tag will be skipped (you must use `cssInline` property for this)

If you have just a few styles to add to the pdf, you can pass it like this:

```
$pdf->content = $htmlContent;
$pdf->cssInline = '.class1 {color: red} .class2 {color:blue}';
```

But if you have alot of styles, you can also consider change the default `cssFile` to any file you want with the correct css. (by default, this property is `@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/bootstrap.min.css`